# How to get TRTTIType for method linked generic type

Tags: delphi, rtti, delphi-10.3-rio

I use Delphi 10.3. It is a kind of routine to get the corresponding `TRTTIType` for instance variables. But is there any way to fill the gap marked as *** missing code *** here:

```
function getGenericTypeName<T> : string;
var
  ctx : TRTTIContext;
  aRT : TRTTIType;
begin
  ctx := TRTTIContext.Create;
  try
    aRT := *** missing code for T *** // Get the TRTTIType for type T
    result := aRT.Name;
  finally
    ctx.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for

```
ctx.GetType(TypeInfo(T))
```

Comment: Thx! I tried TypeInfo without the ctx.GetType but it said 'Record, Class or Interface type requiered'... Now I retype the code and it compiles fine! :)